# How to test for object attributes using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test the `reponse.json` output from a `show` method in a controller:

```
describe "#show" do
 let!(:animal){create(:animal, name:"Cat"}
 let(:params) {{id: animal.id}}

 subject {get :show, params: params}

 context "when animal campaign exists" do
  it "should have the expected keys" do
    subject

    response_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expected_keys = [
      "animal_name",
      "id", 
      ]
      expect(response_json).to include(*expected_keys)
```

The expected object that is output is not being compared to the `expected_keys`:

```
  expected {"animal_name" => "Cat, "animal_id" => 6999} 
  Diff:
       @@ -1,23 +1,23 @@
       -["animal_name",
       - "animal_id"]
```

How can I check for the `expected_keys`?

Comment: try `expect(response_json.keys).to include(*expected_keys)`

Answer (score 1):

While you could use:

```
expect(response_json.keys).to include [""animal_name", "id"]
```

The failure message is going to be very cryptic as it tells us nothing about what you are actually trying to test.

Slightly better is:

```
expect(response_json).to have_key "animal_name"
expect(response_json).to have_key "animal_id"
```

But you can actually test the correctness of the JSON against the model:

```
expect(response_json).to include({
  "animal_name" => "Cat"
  "animal_id" => animal.id
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a weird test to write, but you could just map out the keys from `response.body`.

I don't know what your controller looks like, but I'd guess there's some relational thing going on which prepends `animal_` to your response.

Wouldn't a better test simply be something like this?

```
describe 'GET show' do
  it 'will show an animal campaign' do
    get :show, params: { id: animal.id }
    expect(response.parsed_body).to include 'animal_name'
  end
end
```

Judging from your output that should pass, although I'm not quite sure what exactly you're testing for.